# How to handle Uboot upgrade compatibility with Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, bios

I am working on a device that come with a pre-installed version of Uboot.

During their manufacturing run - they update Uboot to be whatever is most current.

Unfortunately this can create issues with compatibility of the version of Ubuntu we are using (14.04 LTS).

Is there a patch or something that can be done where even if Uboot upgrades - that an older version of Ubuntu will keep working?

Any help would be great!

Best,
Jonathan